# Vertical positioning of content on page

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I've got a document I'm going to generate from some input which basically is a tabularx for each page:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXlll}
\hline \\[3ex]
\commandOne \\
\hline \\[3ex]
\commandTwo \\
\hline 
\end{tabularx}

\clearpage

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXlll}
\hline \\[3ex]
\commandThree \\
\hline \\[3ex]
\commandFour \\
\hline 
\end{tabularx}
```

where `\commandOne`...`\commandFour` generates the table's rows and columns.

The problem is that I want each of the `\hline`s to be placed exactly at the same place on each page (I know that every `\commandN` takes less than half a page).

Is there for example a way I can hardcode the position of the `\hline` and the text following?

Comment: Do you have to use tabularx here or would it be enough to determine a with of that column and then you could a l column with a minipage whre you specified both the width and vertical extent.

Comment: @Paul It maybe better not to use a tabular at all, can you post a sample output somewhere?

Comment: Also would be useful to understand how you determine/specify where the `\hline` is to go.